# Connection to sql server 2008 R2 error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I'm trying to connect for an sql server from my code in asp. my connection string is :

```
<add name="ClassEyesConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=TAJDED-PC;Initial Catalog=ClassEyes;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=classeyes;Password=class123456;connect timeout=50" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but I face the following exception :

> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this usually means that the connection string doesn't point to a an active server, recheck your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled TCP/IP?  By default only Named Pipes is enabled in SQl Server 2008.

Also check that you can connect to the pc (by pinging etc).  If it's your PC, then try the localhost address.

This article shows you how to set up SQL server 2008 for asp.net development, including the steps to enable TCP/IP

http://evonet.com.au/setting-up-sql-server-2008-for-an-asp-net-website-on-iis-7-0/